# C# volatile array items?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, arrays, volatile

I need an array with volatile items, and can't find a way to do that.

```
private volatile T[] _arr;
```

This means that the _arr reference is volatile, however it does not guarantee anything about the items inside the _arr object itself.

Is there any way to mark the _arr's Items as volatile?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The following code built according to binarycoder's answer.
Is this code thread-safe to use?

```
public class VolatileArray<T>
{
    private T[] _arr;

    public VolatileArray(int length)
    {
        _arr = new T[length];
    }

    public VolatileArray(T[] arr)
    {
        _arr = arr;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            T value = _arr[index];
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            return value;
        }

        set
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            _arr[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return _arr.Length; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question needs more love.

Comment: It's not thread safe when T is `long` or `double`, as these are 64 bit values, and you have to read and write them using `Volatile.Read()`and `Volatile.Write()` or some such, otherwise reads and writes are not guaranteed to be atomic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it is possible to pass array elements by reference, you can use `Thread.VolatileRead` and `Thread.VolatileWrite`.

It is useful to understand that the `volatile` keyword works behind the scenes by using `Thread.MemoryBarrier`. You could write:

```
// Read
x = _arr[i];
Thread.MemoryBarrier();

// Write
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
_arr[i] = x;
```

Note that `volatile` and `MemoryBarrier` are advanced techniques that are both easy to get wrong. For example, see [How do I Understand Read Memory Barriers and Volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787450/how-do-i-understand-read-memory-barriers-and-volatile). Usually you are better off with higher level constructs such as `lock`, `Monitor`, `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, and others.

Comment: IIRC, then strictly, the `volatile` keyword entails only a read or write barrier as appropriate, while `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` has a full barrier. The above therefore is slightly heavier than the equivalent use of `volatile` even before we consider that it involves a method call. It is still the best we can do (and as you say, the current implementation of `VolatileRead()` and `VolatileWrite()`).

Answer (score 6):

Use `Volatile.Read(ref array[index])` and `Volatile.Write(ref array[index], value)`.

Class `Volatile` is available since .NET 4.5. It allows to read/write from/to fields, array elements, `ref` parameters, pointers.

Comment: He's concerned about the volatility of the array reference, not the items in it.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky  He clearly stated that he needed volatile access to array items.

Answer (score 3):

I made a little struct that helps keep things clean and OO

```
struct VolatileBoolean {
    public volatile Boolean Value;
}

VolatileBoolean[] arrayOfVolatileBooleans;
public void SomeMethod() {
    if (arrayOfVolatileBooleans[4].Value)
        DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't think that you can</strike>

You can't, `volatile` is defined as a field-modifier (ECMA 334).

And I don't think it will accomplish what you want either.
Consider:

```
 private T[] _arr;

 volatile T v;
 ....  v = _arr[x];
 ....  _arr[x] = v;
```