# Implicit synchronization when creating/joining threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, memory-model

What is the *minimal* framing required for `x`'s type for this code to work, considering the implied synchronization when creating/joining a thread: `std::atomic`? `volatile`? nothing?

```
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>
int main() {
    int x = 123; // ***
    std::thread( [ & ] { assert( x == 123 ); x = 321; } ).join();
    assert( x == 321 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3114174/1769720) to a related question.

Comment: `std::thread( [ & ] { assert( x == 123 ); x = 321; } ).join();` There's no concurrent access to `x`, you could call the lambda sequentially for achieving the same behavior. `volatile` never serves for thread safety, BTW.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The invocation of `std::thread`'s constructor is synchronized and happens before the invocation of the copy of the thread function (30.3.1.2/6).

`thread::join` gives a similar synchronization guarantee: The completion of the thread happens before `join` returns (30.3.1.4/7).

Your code creates a thread and joins it immediately. Although your lambda captures by reference, there is no concurrency (the code runs as-if sequential), and the guarantees provided by `std::thread` make sure that you do not need any special framing to guard `x`. The assertion will never fail.

Assuming your code snippet was different so you actually have concurrent access of some kind, you would have to use `std::atomic` or a mutex. `volatile` would most definitively not be enough (except by coincidence).

Comment: I understand that by the spec `volatile` isn't sufficient because only the `std::atomic` types are declared to be data-race-free, but what is it about `int`, under the hood, that might make it racy? How do I recognize a failure? Is it because the four bytes of the int could be written in two 2-byte chunks on some platforms, whereas on other platforms that have native 32-bit ints it'll happen to just always work even though it's still wrong? On some platforms, could `std::atomic<int>` be just an alias for `int`? Genuinely curious learner here.

Comment: @antiduh It's not just racing on reading or writing that variable alone. Using atomics also constrains reordering.

Comment: @antiduh: The atomic type and its specializations guarantee that you have certain (whichever you choose) ordering guarantees. That is, for example, a dependent write (or an independent write) is guaranteed to be globally visible before an atomic operation. No such guarantee is given by `volatile`. It might "work", but that's coincidence. About writing out integers, assuming mainstream CPUs and proper alignment,  you are right. non-atomic `int` writes are not possible. However, this is not formally guaranteed and not portable, no defined ordering, and RMW ops (e.g. `++x`) are non-atomic too.