# What is a good way of synchronization for initializing constant global values accessed by multiple threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, initialization, synchronization, memory-barriers

I have a set of global values that are initialized at program start and never change during the run. Those values are read from multiple threads, and I want to make sure the initialization is done correctly for all threads.

In this example,

```
int A, B;

void init() {
  A = 1;
  B = 2;
}

void read(int *a, int *b) {
  *a = A;
  *b = B;
}

void f() {
  /* ... */
  read(&a, &b);
  /* ... */
}

int main() {
  init();
  startThread(f);
  /* ... */
}
```

My understanding is that the compiler isn't allowed to put `init` after `startThread` because the side effects of the functions should be sequenced as written, so the machine instructions to store values in `A` and `B` will come before the thread start. However, this doesn't guarantee that the load in `read` from a different thread will happen after the stores are complete because the stores might for some reason be deferred after the loads.

Here's an obvious *fix*.

```
void init() {
  A = 1;
  B = 2;
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
}

void read(int *a, int *b) {
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
  *a = A;
  *b = B;
}
```

It should work if I've read the specs correctly, but the problem is that now, all functions that read those global values need a fence at function entry, and I'd like to avoid this. Unfortunately, all defined memory orders including `memory_order_seq_cst` are defined for cases where the reader is an atomic operation or has a fence.

Under the strong memory model of x86, the example code will work without any fix. I'm looking for a portable solution, but I'm also wondering whether it really could break on a different platform without synchronization.

If synchronization is necessary, what is a good way in this case? Is it possible without being intrusive to all the reader functions?

Comment: Normally you'd just statically initialize them, like `int A=1, B=2;` (then you can even use `const`.)  I guess you mean run-invariant but not *statically* known at compile-time, like `int A=rand(), B=rand();` which is only legal in C++ (and either way involves run-time init)

Comment: @PeterCordes I am initializing them before starting any threads, also in the example. I wrote in the second paragraph why I think that might not work.

Comment: Also, no, `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);` there doesn't do anything. There's no following atomic store to create acq/rel sync between threads based on the barrier.  Just call `init` before starting any other threads; that's guaranteed to work just like in C++.  IIRC, there's a happens-before relationship between code before a thread starts, wrt. code in that thread.  I guess you were thinking you needed manual fences to create that sync, with thread-startup as the atomic operation.

Comment: (sorry for my c++ answer ... my eyes added `++` after the `c` :-) )

Comment: For C++, see [Implicit synchronization when creating/joining threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29684369)