# Why we need Thread.MemoryBarrier()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, memory-barriers

In "C# 4 in a Nutshell", the author shows that this class can write 0 sometimes without `MemoryBarrier`, though I can't reproduce in my Core2Duo:

```
public class Foo
{
    int _answer;
    bool _complete;
    public void A()
    {
        _answer = 123;
        //Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
        _complete = true;
        //Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 2
    }
    public void B()
    {
        //Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
        if (_complete)
        {
            //Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
            Console.WriteLine(_answer);
        }
    }
}

private static void ThreadInverteOrdemComandos()
{
    Foo obj = new Foo();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(obj.A);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(obj.B);

    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

This need seems crazy to me. How can I recognize all possible cases that this can occur? I think that if processor changes order of operations, it needs to guarantee that the behavior doesn't change.

Do you bother to use Barriers?

Comment: Related question: [How do I Understand Read Memory Barriers and Volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787450/how-do-i-understand-read-memory-barriers-and-volatile)

Comment: Another awesome read on the topic is [Joe Albahari's Threading in C# (part 4)](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You are going to have a very hard time reproducing this bug. In fact, I would go as far as saying you will never be able to reproduce it using the .NET Framework. The reason is because Microsoft's implementation uses a strong memory model for writes. That means writes are treated as if they were volatile. A volatile write has lock-release semantics which means that all prior writes must be committed before the current write.

However, the ECMA specification has a weaker memory model. So it is theoretically possible that Mono or even a future version of the .NET Framework might start exhibiting the buggy behavior.

So what I am saying is that it is very unlikely that removing barriers #1 and #2 will have any impact on the behavior of the program. That, of course, is not a guarantee, but an observation based on the current implementation of the CLR only.

Removing barriers #3 and #4 will definitely have an impact. This is actually pretty easy to reproduce. Well, not this example per se, but the following code is one of the more well known demonstrations. It has to be compiled using the Release build and ran outside of the debugger. The bug is that the program does not end. You can fix the bug by placing a call to `Thread.MemoryBarrier` inside the `while` loop or by marking `stop` as `volatile`.

```
class Program
{
    static bool stop = false;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thread begin");
            bool toggle = false;
            while (!stop)
            {
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("thread end");
        });
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        stop = true;
        Console.WriteLine("stop = true");
        Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
        t.Join();
    }
}
```

The reason why some threading bugs are hard to reproduce is because the same tactics you use to simulate thread interleaving can actually fix the bug. `Thread.Sleep` is the most notable example because it generates memory barriers. You can verify that by placing a call inside the `while` loop and observing that the bug goes away.

You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493931/why-do-i-need-a-memorybarrier/3495287#3495287) for another analysis of the example from the book you cited.

Comment: In the book has this example too. I could test and happens.

Comment: Does not repro in vs2015 so far.

Comment: @Brian Gideon May be it is very silly, but I don't understand why the program in your example never ends! Why `while (!stop)` never get `false`? Can you explain a bit more? Or can you please suggest some detailed blog? I read the article OP posted (albahari example), I got confused there too; to me, barrier 1 is enough, why there are other barriers? MSDN says, `MemoryBarrier` prevents instruction re-ordering. Then why only barrier 1 is not sufficient (because `completed` can't be executed before `answer` is set)? I really don't get it.

Comment: @mshsayem There's a couple reasons. 1) In the thread's function, as far as the compiler is concerned, `while(!stop)` is going to be always true, the compiler will see that the thread function won't manipulate the variable and will ignore that check (unless you do `lock` or `Interlocked.Read` or similar). The compiler does not guarantee that the emitted IL will not optimize that out unless you explicitly make it so.

Comment: @mshsayem 2) Some older CPUs (e.g., IA64, AKA "Itanium") did not guarantee cache coherency (on the hardware level) between threads, as in, if the code above happened to be running on two different cores, there is no guarantee that the CPU running the other thread would bother asking the other CPU what it set `stop` to and assume that its cached value (always false) is right. This is what the `lock` ASM prefix was introduced for, though as far as I know this is not as relevant for AMD64 CPUs which have stronger memory guarantees.

Comment: A mental model that might be helpful is to think of it like this: Your threads don't all share the same pile of memory, they have their own local memory and only read or write  shared memory that's accessible by other threads when you explicitly direct them to (by using `lock`, or some fancy combination of `Monitor`, `MemoryFence`, `Interlocked`, etc, note that the latter is definitely language lawyer territory). Even if thread A writes to `stop`, 1) it may not actually write that to RAM, and 2) even if it did, there's no guarantee that thread B will bother to read the value of `stop` from RAM

Answer (score 11):

Odds are *very* good that the first task is completed by the time the 2nd task even starts running.  You can only observe this behavior if both threads run that code simultaneously and there's no intervening cache-synchronizing operations.  There is one in your code, the StartNew() method will take a lock inside the thread pool manager somewhere.

Getting two threads to run this code simultaneously is *very* hard.  This code completes in a couple of nanoseconds.  You would have to try billions of times and introduce variable delays to have any odds.  Not much point to this of course, the real problem is when this happens randomly when you *don't* expect it.

Stay away from this, use the lock statement to write sane multi-threaded code.

Comment: The problem is that I dont need lock here. Method B should never write 0 since _complete just become true after set _answer.
But is just a example.

Comment: @Fujiy: If you remove barrier 1 then the compiler/jitter/processor might re-order `A` so that `_complete` is set to `true` *before* `_answer` is set to `123`. ie, `B` could see that `_complete` is `true` and subsequently read `0` from answer.

Comment: @Fujiy: Likewise if you remove barrier 4: the compiler/jitter/processor might re-order `B` so that `_answer` is read *before* `_complete`. ie, `B` could read `0` from answer while `_complete` is `false` and then subsequently read `true` from `_complete` *after* it has been updated.

Comment: I understand. Maybe this is no easy way to make all consistent, just avoid shared memory.
Most programmer can read this code and don´t see the race condition, because its a implementation detail of jit/processor.

If I put a lock just at "A" method, B still could write 0?

Comment: I would use an AutoResetEvent in this specific case, replacing _complete.  ARE includes the barrier.

Comment: To clarify, the reason I'm not suggest an ARE or any other lock is that the code intentionally allows for a race condition. There's no guarantee that A completes before B. All that's required is that, if B does detect the completion of A, it also correctly gets the answer A generated.

Comment: Volatile is much too weak, it doesn't include a barrier.  The MSDN docs for it only apply to Titanium.

Comment: If I understand correctly, volatile would not prevent reordering of writes (which is why we need barrier 1), but it would prevent caching of stale results by B.

Comment: @Steven: I think that's correct. Except if you have a weaker memory model variant of the CLR then #1 does prevent the writes to `_answer` and `_complete` from being swapped. Do you agree?

Comment: @Brian: Yes, #1 is the only one that really, really matters (if the memory model would otherwise allow out-of-order writes). It matters because we absolutely can't allow `complete` to be set until `answer` is. Then again, if B can do out-of-order reads, it could have already read `answer` before checking `complete`. That's where `volatile` comes in, preventing the stale read of `answer`.

Comment: The Itanium was a disaster in more than one way.  It will take *years* to get rid of these considerations.

Comment: @StevenSudit Using `volatile` alone for thread synchronization is probably not a good idea, it only protects you from a few compiler/jit optimizations, it doesn't do much for the memory model.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `volatile` and `lock`, the memory barrier is built in. But, yes, you do need it otherwise. Having said that, I suspect that you need half as many as your example shows.

Comment: Yes, the author says that Barriers 2 e 3 is just to guarantee that if A run before B, B enter the if

Comment: They're all theorectically needed if a lock-free strategy is desired.

Comment: @Brian: 1 and 4 are needed. I'm not so sure about 2 and 3. It looks as though the worst case is that it loses a race condition that it might or might not have otherwise won.

Comment: @Fujiy: There's absolutely no guarantee that A will complete before B. IF we wanted that, we would need A to acquire a lock and B to wait on it. Otherwise, it is a race condition. What matters for correctness is that, with 1 and 4 in place, there are no circumstances under which the wrong answer is printed. It's always possible that no answer is printed, as this is also correct.

Comment: @Steven: #2 is needed to commit (flush) the write to `_complete`. #3 is need to acquire (refresh) the read of `_complete`. #2 is needed purely on theorectical grounds. The current CLR implementation enforces volatile writes (and so does the x86 and x64 hardware) so removing it will most likely not cause any problems. But, if you contrive a slightly different example with a `while` loop it should be easy to replicate the bug if #3 is missing.

Comment: @Brian: Right, but if #2 doesn't run, then the worst case is that the write is delayed and the completeness test fails. This is the same result if #3 isn't run. It's not a bug, though. There's really no reason to expect A to complete before B. The only bug would be if B saw A as completed, but got the wrong answer.

Comment: @Steven: Yeah, I see your point now. It really boils down to your definition of a bug :) Along the same pandantic lines, #2 is not needed anyway because thread A terminates immediately which generates a barrier automatically. So for various different reasons (including the one you just mentioned) the author's example doesn't quite do justice to explaining all the caveats with lock-free synchronization.

Comment: @Brian: Well, even if A went and did some unrelated work for a few minutes, instead of just terminating, what's the worst case if we remove #2? Nothing: the predicate in B would simply be false. I'm starting to think that the *only* barrier that's strictly needed is #1.

Comment: @Steven: Absolutely! And using a more strict definition of a bug then I agree #1 is the most crucial (except that even it is not mandatory since the CLR already treats writes as volatile).

Comment: @Brian: Looks like the problem is real, but the example source code is not. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Its very difficult to reproduce multithreaded bugs - usually you have to run the test code many times (thousands) and have some automated check that will flag if the bug occurs. You might try to add a short Thread.Sleep(10) in between some of the lines, but again it not always guarantees that you will get the same issues as without it.

Memory Barriers were introduced for people who need to do really hardcore low-level performance optimisation of their multithreaded code. In most cases you will be better off when using other synchronisation primitives, i.e. volatile or lock.

Comment: The problem with `Thread.Sleep` is that it can generate a memory barrier. So using that mechanism to try to reproduce threading bugs can actually fix the bug.

Comment: Combinatorial tests are a relatively good way to test [on a specific architecture/build]. Can easily vary: number of threads (and making sure they 'start' about the same time), work done in each thread (and ratio of access), chance of Thread.Yield (eg. percentage), etc.. the tests should be able to run millions of iterations in just a few seconds. A slightly more "devious" problem than having Thread.Sleep generate a memory barrier is thread-safe code attempting to get data back from threads causing memory barriers and other 'only test' artifacts.. self-defeating reporting D:

Answer (score 2):

I'll just quote one of the great articles on multi-threading:

> Consider the following example:

```
class Foo
{
  int _answer;
  bool _complete;

  void A()
  {
    _answer = 123;
    _complete = true;
  }

  void B()
  {
    if (_complete) Console.WriteLine (_answer);
  }
}
```

> If methods A and B ran concurrently on different threads, might it be
>   possible for B to write “0”? The answer is yes — for the following
>   reasons:
>
> The compiler, CLR, or CPU may reorder your program's instructions to
>   improve efficiency. The compiler, CLR, or CPU may introduce caching
>   optimizations such that assignments to variables won't be visible to
>   other threads right away. C# and the runtime are very careful to
>   ensure that such optimizations don’t break ordinary single-threaded
>   code — or multithreaded code that makes proper use of locks. Outside
>   of these scenarios, you must explicitly defeat these optimizations by
>   creating memory barriers (also called memory fences) to limit the
>   effects of instruction reordering and read/write caching.
>
> Full fences
>
> The simplest kind of memory barrier is a full memory
>   barrier (full fence) which prevents any kind of instruction reordering
>   or caching around that fence. Calling Thread.MemoryBarrier generates a
>   full fence; we can fix our example by applying four full fences as
>   follows:

```
class Foo
{
  int _answer;
  bool _complete;

  void A()
  {
    _answer = 123;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
    _complete = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 2
  }

  void B()
  {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
    if (_complete)
    {
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
    }
  }
}
```

All the theory behind `Thread.MemoryBarrier` and why we need to use it in non-blocking scenarios to make the code safe and robust is described nicely here: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are ever touching data from two different threads, this can occur.  This is one of the tricks that processors use to increase speed - you could build processors that didn't do this, but they would be much slower, so no one does that anymore.  You should probably read something like [Hennessey and Patterson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605967) to recognize all of the various types of race conditions.

I always use some sort of higher level tool like a monitor or a lock, but internally they are doing something similar or are implemented with barriers.