# Thread.MemoryBarrier() and other memory fences capabilities in DNX Core 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dnx, memory-barriers

As far as I'm understanding those trick things, being able to do a full full fence memory barrier is more important on DNX than in standard .Net framework:
- DNX could possibly run on IA64 that has a weaker memory model than x86/x64.
- the Microsoft CLR uses a stronger memory model than the ECMA specification defines.

Quoting from the answer of [Why do I need a memory barrier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556351/why-we-need-thread-memorybarrier#)

> You are going to have a very hard time reproducing this bug. In fact, I would go as far as saying you will never be able to reproduce it using the .NET Framework. The reason is because Microsoft's implementation uses a strong memory model for writes. That means writes are treated as if they were volatile. A volatile write has lock-release semantics which means that all prior writes must be committed before the current write.
>
> However, the ECMA specification has a weaker memory model. So it is theoretically possible that Mono or even a future version of the .NET Framework might start exhibiting the buggy behavior.

However, neither `MemoryBarrier`, `VolatileRead` and `VolatileWrite` are available on `Thread` class.

My questions are:

- Is this a definitive choice?
- What is the best alternative (providing my current code base uses `MemoryBarrier`) to implement lock-free stuff?

Comment: Not sure one can still buy an Itanium system.  But I think ARM has a weak memory model, and ARMs are now supported by .NET Micro at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` method has been moved to `Interlocked.MemoryBarrier()`.

This `Interlocked` method is available on .Net 4.5 (and 4.6) and on DNXCORE50: this is definitely the one to use from now on.

Note that `VolatileRead\Write` are not available.