# WPF Close event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

On a WPF application I have (too easy to complicate it with any MVVM monstrosity)  I start another thread when the main form, is created. The thread is NOT a background thread. I need to be sure that some unmanaged resources I open are correctly cleaned up when the thread closes.

The thread is created and it works under the whole application's life. Now I close the main window (I have ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"). On my Closed event I signalize the thread to terminate and wait for it (Join). When debugging and setting a break point on the Closed logic, it works fine. The thread terminates and the application closes gratefully.

Running the program however it seems like the code in Closed *sometimes* doesn't get executed? The application closes but I see a zombie process in the TaskManager like if the second thread is still running.

Any ideas?

Comment: Showing relevant parts of your code would help us to help you. As a suggestion - have you tried writing debug info to a file - you should get an idea of the sequence of events.

Comment: Have you considered MemoryBarrier [Why we need Thread.MemoryBarrier()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556351/why-we-need-thread-memorybarrier)

Comment: Put some log output to the handler to ensure it be(or not) invoked.

Comment: `The application closes but I see a zombie process in the TaskManager like if the second thread is still running.` You should attach a debugger to the 'zombie process' to check where it's stuck