# Blocked using wait() and notify() in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, producer-consumer

I am writing producer and consumer code using `wait()` and `notify()` in Java.
Thread-0 is created and is invoked on `produce()` and Thread-1 is created and is invoked on `consume()`.

```
public class Processor {

  private volatile List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
  private final int MAX_CAPACITY = 5;
  Object lock = new Object();

  public void produce() throws InterruptedException {

    while (true) {

      while (list.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {
        System.out.println("List is full! Producer is Waiting....");
        synchronized (lock) {
          lock.wait();
        }
      }

      synchronized (lock) {
        int random = new Random().nextInt(100);
        list.add(random);
        System.out.println("Added to list:" + random);
        lock.notify();
      }
    }
  }

  public void consume() throws InterruptedException {

    while (true) {

      while (list.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("List is empty!! Consumer is Waiting...");
        synchronized (lock) {
          lock.wait();
        }
      }

      synchronized (lock) {
        int i = list.remove(0);
        System.out.println("Removed from list:" + i);
        lock.notify();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that during execution, program stops after `produce()`:

```
List is empty!! Consumer is Waiting...
Added to list:22
Added to list:45
Added to list:72
Added to list:91
Added to list:51
List is full! Producer is Waiting....
```

I am not able to understand what's the problem here. I somehow figured out that wrapping the code from `while` loop in `synchronized` block in `produce()` and `consume()` solves the problem.

`produce()`

```
synchronized (lock) {
                while (list.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {
                    System.out.println("List is full! Producer is Waiting....");

                    lock.wait();
                }
```

`consume`

```
synchronized (lock) {
                while (list.size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("List is empty!! Consumer is Waiting...");

                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
```

What is the issue here? Is it a case of Thread starvation or deadlock?

**Edit:** Calling class:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Processor processor = new Processor();

        Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    processor.produce();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    processor.consume();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();


    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call produce and consume methods? Could you please post that code?

Comment: @Divers post edited with calling class.

Comment: This is not a deadlock. A deadlock requires two locks or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you perform `list.size()` it is not thread safe and there is no guarentee you will ever see the value changed in another thread.  The JIT could even inline the value if it detects you are not changing it in that thread.

By placing the `synchronized` block outside the loop you ensure a change in the value is visible (as it is also inside the `while(true)` loop.

Comment: I'd also add: "prefer using `notifyAll` over `notify`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - bad advice.  NotifyAll is inefficient.  If you need to rely on it, then something is suboptimal in your synchronization.

Comment: @StephenC Maybe, but if you have - for example - multiple producers and consumers, then consumers might wake up consumers and producers might wake up producers and if you are unlucky it might take a while before anything happens.

Comment: You should not have the producers and consumers waiting in the same thing.  In fact, that is probably better implemented with a different synchronization construct; e.g. a Queue / Deque

Comment: @StephenC I agree, a BlockingQueue would be much better/simpler, I assume this is just an exercise and no one would actually do this. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I agree. But in most of the Java interview questions, these low level synchronization questions are rampant.

Answer (score 1):

Using `synchronized` outside loop creates [read barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485791/what-are-read-barriers-and-write-barriers-in-synchronized-block). Therefore producer/consumer will see latest `list` inside loop where you are checking `list.size()`. That is why it works after you move `while` loop inside `synchronized` block.

In your case I would also suggest you to use single synchronized block in producer/consumer.

For example in your implementation if `list.size() == 0` becomes `false` for consumer, it will release lock on `lock` object then in the next statement try to re-acquire lock again for consuming the data, which is unnecessary and inefficient. It should be like:

```
public void consume() throws InterruptedException {

  while (true) {
    synchronized (lock) {
      while (list.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("List is empty!! Consumer is Waiting...");

        lock.wait();
      }

      int i = list.remove(0);
      System.out.println("Removed from list:" + i);
      lock.notify();
    }
  }
}
```