# synchronize without volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile

I understand what synchronize and volatile does and where they are used. I just learned volatile and I was confused about when could we use synchronize without volatile. if I synchronize an object I need to block other threads from using the same object , but in most cases I would do that to edit the object, if so I need to have volatile on that attributes I'm editing .

The following code is about race condition and I wonder why I've never seen someone using volatile on count variable :

```
  public synchronized void add(int value){
      this.count += value;
  }
```

shouldn't be count volatile here ?

I'm just trying to figure a case where synchronize can be used without volatile , a piece of code will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evident that `volatile` is not strong enough to implement a counter because it does not guarantee atomicity. However, if reads greatly outnumber modifications, you can combine intrinsic locking and volatile variables to reduce the cost on the common code path. Check this out,

```
public class Counter {
    @GuardedBy("this") private volatile int value;

    public int getValue() { return value; }

    public synchronized int increment() {
        return value++;
    }
}
```

The code uses synchronized to ensure that the increment operation is atomic and uses volatile to guarantee the visibility of the current result. If updates are infrequent, this approach may perform better as the overhead on the read path is only a `volatile` read, which is generally cheaper than a lock acquisition.

Comment: synchronize shouldn't be enough right ?   I was wondering why no one using it in their examples. can I have example for synchronize alone without volatile ? I can't seem to find one because every edit should be visible.

Comment: Here you have both `synchronized` and `volatile`. You can `synchronize` the `getValue()` method too instead of marking it as `volatile` but that would be costly as the answer explains.

Comment: if I synchronize getValue I still need the volatile , how could other threads have the changes visible ?

Comment: If you `synchronize` it then the `volatile` is no longer needed. But that will be slow since it involes a heavy lock acquisition.

Comment: @ Ravindra Ranwala why it is not needed ? does synchronize forces read from memory ?

Comment: `synchronized` provide you visibility same as `volatile`. So it is not needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181800/discussion-between-mohammad-karmi-and-ravindra-ranwala).

Comment: Don't do discussions in chat, coz others will miss that. This site is mainly for learning purpose. So the chatting primarily violates it's main intention.

Comment: @Ravidra no discussion I didnt want to post many messages , it is just add this to the answer "synchronized provide you visibility same as volatile. So it is not needed" which was my question on do we need both together or not

Comment: @ Ravindra Ranwala if you have any doucment about synchronized provide you visibility same as volatile.  it will be great

Comment: @MohammadKarmi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485791/what-are-read-barriers-and-write-barriers-in-synchronized-block https://riptutorial.com/java/example/10870/visualizing-read-write-barriers-while-using-synchronized---volatile https://dzone.com/articles/memory-barriersfences https://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for the documents but I have one doubt, does synchronize always ensure to read consistent data even if that data was manipulated by non-synchronized block ?
synchronized method A(){
this.count  // will it always read latest changes if another thread modifies it in B() method ?
}
 method B(){
this.conunt++;
....}

Comment: Read this book https://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601

Comment: @RavindraRanwala thanks , but can you please provide me an answer for the question I tagged Peter on ?

Comment: @MohammadKarmi No, synchornized only guarantees visibility of changes that were made within synchronized blocks of the same lock. However that was a good question.

Comment: @MohammadKarmi The writer needs a write barrier and the reader needs a read barrier. Otherwise, the value write might not get propagated.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is this sentence true "The thread memory flushes all its variables, i.e. it has all of its variables effectively read from "main" memory ." I read it from here http://javaexp.blogspot.com/2007/12/difference-between-volatile-and.html.
if the sentence above is true then visibility will be guaranteed  on changes from different locks .

Comment: @PeterLawrey this is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52794312/synchronize-on-different-object-visbility