# synchronize on different object visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

the following code shows synchronization on different object than this:

```
public class A {

int a,b,c,d;

public void method1(Object x){
   synchronized(x){
     // is a ,b ,c ,d guarantee visibility ? 
   }
}

   public synchronized void method2() {
        a++;
    }
}
```

I know there will be a problem to edit a , b ,c ,d with having different lock in method1 and method2 , but the question is the changes flushed by method2 be visible to method1? because they don't use the same lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only read `a`, on x64 this will happen to work as memory barriers are not limited to specific memory locations. However, my understanding is that Java doesn't guarantee this will be thread safe as the locks apply to different objects. Certainly, if you increment `a` in the first method, it won't be thread safe.

Comment: from your answer I understand this sentence is true right ? "The thread memory flushes all its variables, i.e. it has all of its variables effectively read from "main" memory ." , even though x will be read from main memory ? ( I know x is an Object and should be in heap , but does that force any synchronize block to read each variable inside from main memory ? )

Comment: @MohammadKarmi for performance reasons, the L2 caches of the cores pass the latest values between them, so the value doesn't have to go to L3 or main memory.

Comment: last question to understand everything . let's say method2 is synchronized on same x object from method1 will the visibility be guaranteed to x ,a,b,c,d  in method1 ?

Comment: @MohammadKarmi yes.

Answer (score 1):

> I know there will be a problem to edit a , b ,c ,d with having different lock in method1 and method2 , but the question is the changes flushed by method2 be visible to method1 ? because they don't use the same lock.

Without any other synchronization, Java provides no guarantees about whether or when a modification to `A.a` performed via `A.method2()` in one thread would be visible to `A.method1()`, either inside or outside the `synchronized` block within, in a different thread.  A program in which that question arises is not properly synchronized, so its behavior is undefined.

Comment: let's say method2 is synchronized on same x object ( not this ) will the visibility be guaranteed to x ,a,b,c,d ?

Comment: If `method2` contained a synchronized block, then on an execution of that method in which that block is synchronized on some object `o1`, code inside that block will observe any writes previously performed by the same or any other block synchronized on the same object `o1`.  Likewise, when that `o1` is the argument to `A.method1()`, code in that method's synchronized block will observe any writes previously performed by that or any other block synchronized on the same `o1`, including the one in `method2()`.

Comment: @MohammadKarmi, synchronizing on the same object furthermore means that the execution of one synchronized block always either precedes or follows execution of the other, though it says nothing about which comes first.  That has further implications, well beyond the fact that the two executions do not overlap.