# Debug vs Release C# code

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isComplete = false;

        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (!isComplete) i += 0;
        });

        t.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        isComplete = true;
        t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("complete!");

    }
```

The program will hung in release mode and will give an output in debug mode ("complete!").

What is the reason for that?

Thanks.

Comment: "Why this unsafe multithreading code behaves erratically" is not really useful question... While it is entertaining coding puzzle there is zero practical value in this...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I wouldn't be surprised to see such code in real life in a production environment and people wandering why it's wrong and not working like on their development machine and then deciding to run debug builds in production. All just because of some optimizations they aren't aware of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of the variable `isComplete` is most likely being loaded into a register in your release build to avoid the round-trip to read value from memory in the while loop.

Therefore, the loop will not "detect" when the value of `isComplete` is changed to true.

You need to indicate to the compiler that this variable is `volatile`: essentially telling the system to **not** make assumptions based on code executing in the current thread whether or not this memory changes (i.e., some other thread or process might change it).

See this SA answer for some details:

[How do I Understand Read Memory Barriers and Volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788199/1981581) - StackOverflow

If you want to dig even deeper into memory and concurrency, then here is an excellent article by Fabian Giesen about cache coherency in multi-core systems:

[Cache coherency primer](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/cache-coherency/)

[Atomic operations and contention](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/atomics-and-contention/)

Here are good reasons why you should just use a lock unless you know what you are doing:

[Volatile keyword usage vs Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384758/1981581) - StackOverflow

Here is MSDN doc on `Volatile.Read` method:

[Volatile.Read Method()](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Note that without some more detailed explanation (see above SA thread, or google) of the terms, the description in the MSDN documentation can be hard to translate into what is actually going on.

Here is the MSDN doc on `volatile` keyword:

[volatile (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)

In C# this keyword will use a half-fence (as far as I know); you will also find this keyword in C for example, but there it only affects compiler optimizations (does not insert a memory barrier) as it was originally intended for reading memory-mapped I/O.

**Example**:

```
        bool isComplete = false;

        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (!Volatile.Read(ref isComplete)) i += 0;
        });

        t.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        isComplete = true;
        t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("complete!");
```

Comment: Side note: `volatile` is wrong solution to write correct multithreading code, but it is fine for this fake example.

Comment: Indeed `volatile` keyword is not a magical solution for solving concurrency problems. Actual problems require careful consideration of all possible order of executions, possible instruction re-ordering by compiler or CPU, and on certain obscure platforms even cache consolidation between cores.

Comment: Local variables cannot be declared volatile. That would not compile.

Comment: He should not use the keyword, use a half-fence memory barrier: ex `Volatile.Read`.

Comment: I think this would be a better answer if it actually explained what `volatile` does (other than "makes the program work").

Comment: There are already several answers on SA which describe memory fences in detail. I can refer to one of them, but would be pointless to add yet another in-depth explanation.

Comment: A link would be sufficient, or even just a quick summary.

Comment: maybe even just quote MSDN: "The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time. Fields that are declared volatile are not subject to compiler optimizations that assume access by a single thread. This ensures that the most up-to-date value is present in the field at all times."

Comment: You might want to use `Volatile.Write(ref isComplete, true);`

Comment: I don't believe that that is necessary in this example. `Volatile.Write` is to ensure that writes are not re-ordered; that all previous writes are flushed before the next write. You might write a bunch of data and then set one flag which indicates that data is ready to be read, by using `Volatile.Write` when setting the flag you ensure that writes are not re-ordered so that the flag is set before all the other data has been flushed. This way you ensure that if the flag is set, then you can safely read the other data.